# Call functions until one of them does not return None

Tags: python

i want to call different Rest-API's.
If a call does not work, i would like to try the next one.
My current solution:

```
def func1():
    try:
        return apicall1()
    except:
        return None


def func2():
    try:
        return apicall2()
    except:
        return None


def tryFunctions():

    df = func1()
    if df is None:
        df = func2()
    return df

df = tryFunctions()
```

Is there any more convenient way to do this?

Comment: func1() and func2() will always return None in this setup

Comment: Sry, fixed it...

Comment: Use generator function,make a generator expression of all functions and yield them on demand, if u dont get a response yield next else stop. It will save u memory and it'll be fast too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with only two functions you could just do:

```
df = df if (df := func1()) is not None else func2()
```

With more than two functions, set up an iterable of functions:

```
funcs = [func1, func2, func3, ...]
df = next((df for f in funcs if (df := f()) is not None), None)
```

(Walrus operator `:=` requires Python 3.8.)

Answer (score 2):

```
def tryFunctions():
    for func in [apicall1, apicall2]:
        try:
            return func()
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this. (Note that `tryFunctions` function here is the actual answer, and the `apicall*` functions and the final `print` statement are test code to illustrate the functionality.)

```
def apicall1():
    raise RuntimeError

def apicall2():
    return "it was 2"

def tryFunctions():
    for apicall in apicall1, apicall2:
        try:
            return apicall()
        except:
            pass
    return "none of them worked"

print(tryFunctions())
```

gives:

```
it was 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could chain calls together in some reasonable way.

```py
def call_chainer(*funcs):
    for f, args in funcs:
        result = f(*args)
        if result is not None:
            return result
```

With this function you can construct a list of tuples `(callable, [arg1, arg2, argN])` that should be tried in order.

```py
def tryFunctions():
    functions = [(func1, []), (func2, [])]
    return call_chainer(*functions)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func1():
    try:
        return apicall1()
    except:
        return func2()


def func2():
    try:
        return apicall2()
    except:
        return None


def tryFunctions():

    All_func = [func1(),func2(),func3(),...,funcn()]
    for funct in All_func:
      if funct is None:
        continue
      else:
        return funct

df = tryFunctions()
```

Comment: I don't recommend this. This makes `func1` functionally dependent on `func2`. That seems like a very bad thing.

Comment: Adam the question says that if first function fails then it will move on to second one.

Comment: But it's not `func1`'s responsibility to implement that logic. Think about this pattern when there are more than two functions here -- does it make sense to have a `func1` through `func10` all redirecting flow to the next? What happens when you decide to remove `func5`? Do you modify `func4` to point to `func6`? What happens when you want to re-order the calls? I'm not saying it won't work, I'm saying the design could be workshopped a bit.

Comment: Thanks, Adam Smith for pointing out the loophole do this new edit will work fine?

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    api = True

    try:
        api = apicall1()
    except Exception:
        continue

    try:
        api = apicall2()
    except Exception:
        continue

    try:
        api = apicall3()
    except Exception:
        continue

    if api:
        print("ERROR")
        exit()
```

i think this is the best readable method